# DataGrid not displaying on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, datagrid

I am trying to create a DataGrid but it's not displaying when I load the page. I am trying to create a function for the DataGrid called BuildGrid.

```
protected void LoadJob(int JobID)
{
        DataGrid db = JobClass.Job_Piece.BuildGrid();

        db.DataSource = jb.Pieces;
        db.DataBind();
}
```

So the BuildGrid function is:

```
public static DataGrid BuildGrid()
        {
            DataGrid NewDg = new DataGrid();

            NewDg.DataKeyField = "ID";
            NewDg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            NewDg.CssClass = "tblResults";
            NewDg.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "tblResultsHeader";
            NewDg.AlternatingItemStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyleAlt";
            NewDg.ItemStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyle";


            NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("AdvisedQty", "No Of Pces"));
            NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("PieceTypeString", "Pces Type"));
            NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("ReceivedQty", "Rcvd Pces"));
            NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("Reason", "Reason"));

            NewDg.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00);

            return NewDg;
        }
```

Comment: check answer it having what you missed over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse its not going to display on the page ...because you created datagrid in codebehind file but you not added created grid to page i.e. html ..you need to add created datagrid to page dynamically as you created it dynamically

code to add

```
   // DataGrid1 is added to the PlaceHolder
   PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(DataGrid1);
```

aspx page code

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
  <asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</form>
```

once you page palceholder in you aspx page you codebehind will  be

protected void LoadJob(int JobID)
{
        DataGrid db = JobClass.Job_Piece.BuildGrid();

```
    db.DataSource = jb.Pieces;
    db.DataBind();
    PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(db);
```

}